# jquery ui datepicker Default Week number on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I get this working it gets on week selection "Week number: #"   on main field and on alternate field get "yy-mm-dd"

On load I get "yy-mm-dd" from current date (Today) On both fields, but I want on load  "Week number: #" on main and "yy-mm-dd" on alternate, from current date.

```
    $(function() {

    var currentDate = new Date();
    $( "#fecha" ).datepicker( {
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
       showWeek: true,
        firstDay: 1,
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        altField: "#date1",
        altFormat: "yy-mm-dd",

        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            $(this).val("Semana Numero: " + $.datepicker.iso8601Week(new Date(dateText)));
        }


    });
     $("#fecha").datepicker("setDate", currentDate);
});
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with the datepicker plugin, but it looks like it doesn't have any events you can trigger on it.

Anyways, this might not be the best approach, but what I did was loop through all the datepicker date `<a>`'s and trigger a click on the date that matches today's date.

https://jsfiddle.net/b3vstmef/

Answer (score 0):

I was just looking over the datepicker and it doesnt look like you can trigger the onselect so I found that the code below will work instead.

```
$(function() {
   var currentDate = new Date();
   $( "#fecha" ).datepicker( {
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
   showWeek: true,
    firstDay: 1,
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    altField: "#date1",
    altFormat: "yy-mm-dd",

    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        populate(this, dateText)
    }


});
 $("#fecha").datepicker("setDate", currentDate);
});
function populate(field, d){
$(field).val("Semana Numero: " + $.datepicker.iso8601Week(new Date(d)));
}

populate($( "#fecha" ), $("#date1").val());
```

See it in action:
https://jsfiddle.net/y3llowjack3t/ycok5cwx/